# Defining paragraph with RTL direction in word file by OpenXML in C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

How to set the right-to-left direction for a paragraph in word with OpenXML in C#? I use codes below to define it but they won't make any change:

```
 RunProperties rPr = new RunProperties();

 Style style = new Style();
 style.StyleId = "my_style";
 style.Append(new Justification() { Val = JustificationValues.Right });
 style.Append(new TextDirection() { Val = TextDirectionValues.TopToBottomRightToLeft });
 style.Append(rPr);
```

and at the end I will set this style for my paragraph:

```
...
heading_pPr.ParagraphStyleId = new ParagraphStyleId() { Val = "my_style" };
```

But is see no changes in the output file.

I have found some post but they didn't help me at all,like:

[Changing text direction in word file](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/oxmlsdk/thread/9900a3da-5d68-4d7a-a5f6-f45c473a73f9/)

How can solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `BiDi` class to set the text direction to RTL for a paragraph.
The following code sample searches for the first paragraph in a word document
and sets the text direction to RTL using the `BiDi` class:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument doc =
   WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"test.docx", true))
{
  Paragraph p = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.ChildElements.First<Paragraph>();

  if(p == null)
  {
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Paragraph not found.");
    return;
  }

  ParagraphProperties pp = p.ChildElements.First<ParagraphProperties>();

  if (pp == null)
  {
    pp = new ParagraphProperties();
    p.InsertBefore(pp, p.First());
  }

  BiDi bidi = new BiDi();
  pp.Append(bidi);

}
```

There are a few more aspects to bi-directional text in Microsoft Word.
*SanjayKumarM* wrote an article about how right-to-left text content
is handled in Microsoft Word. See [this](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2007/04/09/rtl-text.aspx) link for more information.

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me to set the direction Right to Left

```
var run = new Run(new Text("Some text"));
var paragraph = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph(run);
paragraph.ParagraphProperties = new ParagraphProperties()
{
    BiDi = new BiDi(),
    TextDirection = new TextDirection()
    {
        Val = TextDirectionValues.TopToBottomRightToLeft
    }
};
```