# Best way to write a word document in C# (Bi-Directional)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word, bidirectional

I've been struggling in the last few days, trying to write a Word document.
I've tried downloading DocX by (Novacode) which was not a big success, then moved to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word library which was better but still, not a huge success.

The problem is that I'm trying to write a Right-To-Left document, which is of course mixed with different punctuation. The moment I add punctuation the entire line is reversed.

I get many lines written from Database, write them the way they are in the document, and I can not manipulate them, unlike titles and stuff, which I can manipulate, reverse stuff and get the lines the way I want, after struggling.

I've seen some answers saying I should use a specific char which 'tells' the reading algorithm it is about to face a Right-To-Left line, but here most data is derived from database.

Has anyone faced that kind of problem and can give some advices?

Comment: not standard solution, is to create HTML page/file and rename extension to be .doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To whoever finds it relevant, and none of the above helped, I found this answer the best for Right-To-Left documents:

```
oDoc.Paragraphs.ReadingOrder = Word.WdReadingOrder.wdReadingOrderRtl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with the [Open XML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854(v=office.15).aspx) and using the [BiDi class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461035/defining-paragraph-with-rtl-direction-in-word-file-by-openxml-in-c-sharp)?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd452407(v=office.12).aspx