# How To Chanage OpenXml Wordprocessing Text Direction?

Tags: c#, text, ms-word, openxml, direction

I'm trying to open a word document and change its text direction to correct ones, here :

```
IEnumerable<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text> texts = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text>();

foreach (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text text in texts)
{ -> Change text Direction <- }
doc.Save();
doc.Close();
doc.Dispose();
```

I have those ***texts***, but how can I change their direction to right-to-left?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461035/defining-paragraph-with-rtl-direction-in-word-file-by-openxml-in-c-sharp) answer your question?

Comment: @pfx thanks for your answer but as I said, I want to change direction on text and not on paragraph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BiDi` class set the text direction to right-to-left:

```cs
IEnumerable<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text> texts = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text>();

var run = new Run(texts);
var p = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph(run);
p.ParagraphProperties = new ParagraphProperties()
{
    BiDi = new BiDi(),
    TextDirection = new TextDirection()
    {
        Val = TextDirectionValues.TopToBottomRightToLeft
    }
};
```